# Docker continuously writing to syslog, filling entire disk

Tags: docker, syslog

The Docker daemon is writing the following error message to my syslog file so many times, that I had to uninstall it to be able to use my computer:

> Nov 17 14:49:14 mypc docker.dockerd[28517]:
>   time="2019-11-17T14:49:14.045361383+01:00" level=error msg="failed to
>   get event" error="rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = all SubConns
>   are in TransientFailure, latest connection error: connection error:
>   desc = \"transport: Error while dialing dial unix
>   /run/containerd/containerd.sock: connect: permission denied\""
>   module=libcontainerd namespace=plugins.moby

I have no idea why this behaviour started and would appreciate some advice, as I am a big fan of Docker. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi Borzi, what operating system are you using? which version of docker does this relate to? Have you added your user to the docker group in order to properly control docker with your non-root user?

Comment: I think there's a dupe of this over on server fault, or possibly super user.

Comment: Thanks for the responses and inquiries. Host machine os is an Ubuntu 18.04. I will try to install it with an alternative method to snap first, then try and double check the user group. I'll report back asap!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got the same issue today myself.

Please have a look here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/snapd/+bug/1852720

sudo snap remove docker

Comment: I already removed Docker so it is no longer on my system - does this mean I should install it via a method that is not snap?

Comment: `sudo snap remove docker` finally ended after 27 min on my Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: I ended up just using the docker version from the repository, if anyone is looking for an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

This is an Ubuntu bug. User either

```
sudo snap remove docker
```

Or

```
sudo apt purge docker.io
```

...to uninstall and truncate the syslog:

```
sudo truncate --size=0 /var/log/syslog
```

If you run into trouble, try truncating once before and after uninstalling.